Azure DevOps error Repository with name or identifier does not exist or you do not have permissions
I am converting a Classic Azure build pipeline into a YAML pipeline and I have this step defined:
parameters:
  RestoreBuildProjects: '**/*.csproj'
  buildConfiguration: 'Any CPU'
  TestProjects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'

stages:

- stage: Build
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  
  jobs:
  - job: Build_Application
    continueOnError: false
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
    - checkout: self
      persistCredentials: true
    
    - script: |
        npm install --no-fund -g git+https://builduser:$(System.AccessToken)@ourrepos.visualstudio.com/Projects/_git/Util
      displayName: 'npm install util'
      workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)

This fails with the following error:
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote https://builduser:***@ourrepos.visualstudio.com/Projects/_git/Util
npm ERR! remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Util does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
npm ERR! fatal: repository 'https://ourrepos.visualstudio.com/Projects/_git/Util/' not found

I have tried:

With and without the checkout step
With and without sudo npm
Switching builduser for user
Passing the System.AccessToken in from the parent YAML file as a parameter
Ensured Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is OFF
Ensured Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines is OFF
Ensured Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines is OFF

And variations of these.
The script step in question does, of course, work in the Classic pipeline, but not in the YAML pipeline and I can't help but think I am missing some detail of running scripts or accessing environment variables specific to YAML.
Is there anything else I might need to do?
EDIT: I have solved the problem but not by fixing the issue. Strangely, by simply recreating the pipeline file using - yes, truly - the same code, I now have the command working just fine. I do not know why but when I have time I will go through the answers in detail and try to find out what happened, but for now the problem is gone. Thanks to everyone who helped.


remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier Util does
not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are
attempting.

As you could run your pipeline in the classic pipeline, you may check the Build job authorization scope in your classic pipeline.

If it is Current project, you may enable Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
And check the Service Account: {Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name}) has the Read Permission in your target repo(Util): Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target repos(Util) -> Security.

If Build job authorization scope is Project Collection.

You may disable the Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines for your project ourrepos.visualstudio.com/Projects/
and check the Service Account: Project Collection Build Service (OrganizationName) has the Read Permission in your target repo(Util):
Project Settings -> Repositories -> Target repos(Util) -> Security.


The build job authorization is set to Project collection. Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is set to OFF. Project Collection Build Service Read property is set to Allow (System).

As build job authorization is set to Project collection, the Util repo is in the same organization and in different project right?

Yes, that's correct.

Since Util repo is in the same organization but in different project, as per the  error message, please follow below items for a check. I tested your yaml and it's working on my side:

You can get the correct git url when you clone repository:


The npm install command should be like below:
npm install --no-fund -g git+https://builduser:$(System.AccessToken)@{orgname}.visualstudio.com/{projectname}/_git/{reponame}

on your project which have your YAML pipeline, make sure:

Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines is OFF.
Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines is OFF.

on SOURCE repository, Make sure Project Collection Build Service Accounts has read permission.


My pipeline result:

